# Update is issue

Tags: t-sql

This update was run again our db.  It said that it updated 5587 which was the correct number of records but in actuality it updated man, many more.  Why was that.  Thanks in advance.

```
 UPDATE LIVE.SORDERP
 SET SOQSTA_0  ='1'

 WHERE SORDERP.SOHNUM_0 in (
 SELECT DISTINCT
            h.SOHNUM_0
        FROM Set_to_Close h
        )
```

Comment: UPDATE LIVE.SORDERP
 SET SOQSTA_0  ='1'

 WHERE SORDERP.SOHNUM_0 in (
 SELECT DISTINCT
            h.SOHNUM_0
        FROM Set_to_Close h
        )

Comment: Could it be that the values of `SOHNUM_0` are not distinct? Perhaps the number of records you're expecting is the number of distinct values?

Comment: What do you get back from `SELECT count(*) FROM LIVE.SORDERP WHERE SORDERP.SOHNUM_0 in (
 SELECT DISTINCT
            h.SOHNUM_0
        FROM Set_to_Close h
        );`? Whatever the answer is, is the number of records that were updated.

Comment: "in actuality". On what basis?  How was that checked?

Comment: The select statement returned 5887 records and that is what the update date said as well but more than that was updated.

Comment: How do you know more where updated?  How are you validating that?   Are you then selecting where SOQSTA_0  ='1' after you update?  Could there have already been records with that value before the update?